# why i'm getting AttributeError when using 'enchant.DictWithPWL()' from 'enchant' module?

Tags: python, attributeerror, pyenchant, word-list, enchant

I'm using **enchant** module. It has an attribute `DictWithPWL` to add personal word list to existing dictionary that is pre-defined. But i'm getting below error:

```
def dictionary_words_finder(word_lst):
    meaningful_word = []
    # creating a dictionary object for checking a word is in dictionary or not and also adding 
    # our personal word list from words.txt
    eng_dictionary = enchant.DictWithPWL("en_US", 'words.txt')
    for word in word_lst:
    
      if not eng_dictionary.check(word):
        continue
      else:
        meaningful_word.append(word)
    
    return meaningful_word`
```

But i'm getting below error:

`AttributeError: module 'enchant' has no attribute 'DictWithPWL'`

Please let me know if there any other way for doing this task if you don't have a solution to above problem.

I've installed the **enchant** module using `!pip install enchant`. **Enchant** module got installed successfully but the problem is not resolved. Also I've search for other methods for doing same task but can't find any such module or methods.

I expect that above written code should not throw `AttributeError` by making some changes to the above code.

I've also gone through documentation here --> https://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/tutorial.html
`enchant.DictWithPWL` is still in their documentation but can't get where i'm doing it wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You installed the wrong package. The package you're trying to use is named `PyEnchant` in PyPI. Try uninstalling `enchant` and installing `PyEnchant`.

Comment: Thanks @ConchDev, changing the module to PyEnchant really worked !